# Whenever I call a method inside another method I get TypeError cannot read undefined

Tags: javascript, function, methods, hoisting

I'm still fairly new to JS and I'm building a project but I am not making much progress. I have a class called AppContainer and inside I'm trying to create logic that will run a trivia game. I have one of my methods working(startTrivia). But when I attempt to call/use another method inside of it(getQuestions) I get the error:

**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getQuestions' of undefined".***

I've tried placing the method above the method it's being called in but still no luck. I have also tried to store the method in a variable first and still same error.

Maybe what I'm trying to do is not possible? Help is greatly appreciated. (Sorry in advance to the excessive commented out code)

```js
class  AppContainer  {  
  questions  =   [];  
  themes  =   [];  
  url  =  "http://localhost:3000";  
  score  =   {};


    
  btn1  =  document.getElementById("person");  
  btn2  =  document.getElementById("species");  
  btn3  =  document.getElementById("spaceships");  
  btn4  =  document.getElementById("planets");  
  btn5  =  document.getElementById("films");  
  btn6  =  document.getElementById("vehicles");  
  allButtons  =  document.getElementById("all-start");

    
  bindEventListener()  {
    const  allButtons  =  this.allButtons;
    const startTrivia =  this.startTrivia;
    this.btn1.addEventListener("click",  function (event)  {
      //event.stopPropagation();
      allButtons.style.visibility  =  "hidden";
      console.log(event);
      startTrivia(event);
    });
    this.btn2.addEventListener("click",  function (event)  {
      //event.stopPropagation();
      allButtons.style.visibility  =  "hidden";
      startTrivia(event);
    });
    this.btn3.addEventListener("click",  function (event)  {
      //event.stopPropagation();
      allButtons.style.visibility  =  "hidden";
      startTrivia(event);
    });
    this.btn4.addEventListener("click",  function (event)  {
      //event.stopPropagation();
      allButtons.style.visibility  =  "hidden";
      startTrivia(event);
    });
    this.btn5.addEventListener("click",  function (event)  {
      //event.stopPropagation();
      allButtons.style.visibility  =  "hidden";
      startTrivia(event);
    });
    this.btn6.addEventListener("click",  function (event)  {
      //event.stopPropagation();
      allButtons.style.visibility  =  "hidden";
      startTrivia(event);
    });  
  }




    
  startTrivia(elem)  {

      
    const triviaBox  =  document.getElementById("trivia-container");
    let firstButton = document.getElementById("person");
    //const getQuestions = this.getQuestions;

    //checking to see if the event target constains a specific classList button
         //if (elem.target.classList.contains("start-btn-person")) {
    // console.log('OHHHH YEAAAH!');
          //triviaBox.style.visibility = "visible";
           //console.log("how do we pivot?");
    // this.getQuestions();
    //}   
    console.log(elem.target)
    if (elem.target == firstButton) {
      console.log("Eurerka!")
      triviaBox.style.visibility  =  "visible";
      this.getQuestions();


    } else {
      console.log("it didnt work")

    };


      
  }

    
  getQuestions()  {     // make fetch request to /questions, then call renderQuestions
        
    fetch(this.url  +  "/questions")      .then((resp)  =>  resp.json())

             //populate the questions and theme properties with the returned data
            .then((data)  =>  {        
        data.forEach((question)  =>  {          
          new  Question(question.name,  question.theme);        
        });

                
        this.renderQuestions();      
      })      .catch((err)  =>  alert(err));  
  }

    
  renderQuestions()  {     // creat DOM nodes and insert data into them to render in the DOM
        
    const  personButton  =  document.getElementById("person");    
    const  filmsButton  =  document.getElementById("films");    
    const  spaceshipsButton  =  document.getElementById("spaceships");    
    const  speciesButton  =  document.getElementById("species");    
    const  vehiclesButton  =  document.getElementById("vehicles");    
    const  planetsButton  =  document.getElementById("planets");

        
    this.questions.forEach((question)  =>  {      
      const  option  =  document.createElement("option");      
      option.innerText  =  question.name;

             //switch (question.theme.name) {
             //  case "person":
             //        personButton.appendChild(option);

             //         break;

             //   case "films":
             //    filmsButton.appendChild(option);

             //    break;

             //  case "spaceships":
             //    spaceshipsButton.appendChild(option);

             //     break;

             //   case "species":
             //     speciesButton.appendChild(option);

             //     break;

             //       case "vehicles":
             //     vehiclesButton.appendChild(option);

             //      break;

             //    case "planets":
             //    planetsButton.appendChild(option);

             //   break;
             //   default:
             //code block

             //  }
          
    });    
    document.body.appendChild(option);  
  }
}

const app = new AppContainer;

app.bindEventListener();
//app.startTrivia();
app.getQuestions()
```

Comment: Looks fine here, if `bindEventListener` is commented out

Comment: Try `const app = new AppContainer();` instead of `const app = new AppContainer;`.